# how do i delete the contents of a table using python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql

HI all i am trying to delete the contents of my tabel before entering new data and i cant seem to get it to work , i keep on getting a error or is there a better way then i am trying to do it, here is the code thank you all for your help in advance

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error



print ("Clearning Flight Data table for new data")


try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='flightdata',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='*****')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    Delete_all_rows = """flightinfo """
    cursor.execute(Delete_all_rows)
    connection.commit()
    print("All Record Deleted successfully ")

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to Delete all records from database table: {}".format(error))
finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")


print ("Running Sydney KWS Domestic update")
import syd_kws_dom


print ("Running Sydney KWS International update")
import syd_kws_int
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `cursor.execute('delete from flightinfo')`.

Comment: that seemed to work mate  so i dont need the delete_all_rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can just execute `delete` query using `cursor.execute`.

```py
Delete_all_rows = """delete from flightinfo """
cursor.execute(Delete_all_rows)
```